# User Data given in Launch Configuration not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Am new to Terraform, am creating Launch Configuration with some user data & using Auto-Scaling-Group to launch the Launch Configuration, but defined "User Data is not working
My code:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "mylc" {
  name          = "lc-1" # Name of Launch config
  image_id      = "ami-0e306788ff2473ccb"  #Image-id
  instance_type = "t2.micro" #type of Instance
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.webserver-sg.id}"]  #Attaching created Security groups
  key_name     = "terraform" # Attaching ssh key
  user_data= <<-EOF # creating user Data
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo su -
  yum update -y
  yum install httpd - y
  service httpd start
  yum install java -y
  EOF
}
```

Comment: Some details on "not working" would be helpful. Is the instance started, but the script is not executed, or what?

Comment: the line:
 user_data= <<-EOF # creating user Data
 #!/bin/bash
should be:
 user_data= <<-EOF
# creating user Data
 #!/bin/bash
because you coul not add a comment in the the same line with <<-EOF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Data runs as the root user. You should not use `sudo` in a User Data script.

You can also examine the User Data logs to view any error messages: `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the bash contained in user_data needs to not have any white spacing in front of it. Essentially it sees tabs before the commands.

```html
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "mylc" {
  name          = "lc-1" # Name of Launch config
  image_id      = "ami-0e306788ff2473ccb"  #Image-id
  instance_type = "t2.micro" #type of Instance
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.webserver-sg.id}"]  #Attaching created Security groups
  key_name     = "terraform" # Attaching ssh key
  user_data= <<-EOF # creating user Data
#!/bin/bash
sudo su -
yum update -y
yum install httpd - y
service httpd start
yum install java -y
  EOF
}
```